# Error: Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 540

Tags: json, firebase, error-handling, deployment, syntax-error

I'm trying to deploy a project with `firebase init`.
When I get to the part that asks me this: "What file should be used for Realtime Database Security Rules? database.rules.json", I press enter and an error appears:

`Error: Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 540`

What should I do? Help pls.

Comment: What does `database.rules.json` look like?

Comment: when prompt with database file name use `database.rules` , and remove `.json` extension

Comment: you need to remove Comments `// These rules grant access to a node matching the authenticated
// user's ID from the Firebase auth token` in your FIrebase Realtime Database rules, apparently Comments are not permitted in JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `--debug` argument I've found out that if there isn't a `database.rules.json` file in the init directory, it will automatically copy what is online in the project. But here's the problem: If the database hast been initialized yet, it will return invalid json (since the rules haven't been setup yet).

So here's how to fix:

- Create your own `database.rules.json` file in your project directory and configure it with valid json.

```json
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": false
    }
}
```

- When you run firebase init and get to the part where it asks you `What file should be used for Realtime Database Security Rules?` use the already created file (so usually just 'database.rules.json').
- If you pointed to the correct file it will ask you `File database.rules.json already exists. Do you want to overwrite it with the Realtime Database Security Rules for insektenhotel-default-rtdb f rom the Firebase console?` (This is automatically yes if the files doesn't exist, causing the problem). Say **No**.

It should work now.